# Why don't I get a bell curve in the torque vs rotor position plot?

Tags: current, torque, pmsm, rotor, plot

I have designed a inset PMSM. I tried to plot the torque vs. rotor position plot but I am not getting a bell curve. Like at the torque must be maximum only when theta is 90 degrees.

I don't know where the mistake is. Is it due to the phase currents?
I have given the phase currents as Ir=-2Im, Iy=Im, Ib=Im, where Im is 4A.

I think this is where the mistake is.  Justify my statement and also theta is taken with respect to phase R as reference and the rotor position or rotor load angle is evaluated.

[image]

Comment: how about providing a schematic, description of what you are measuring/plotting, sample results and so on? There are some fine engineers on here but not so many psychics.

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: You should get a sine/cosine curve, not a bell curve. But without plots, we can just guess.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but i could get only these values as i use FEMM to calculate the torque for each rotor position and it already took me a lot of time, but as you can see clearly, this doesn't depict a bell curve.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I am trying to plot a torque Vs rotor position curve, this must represent a bell curve. As you know, the increase in load angle increases the torque up to 90 degrees, then it starts decreases...

Comment: @MarkoBuršič sorry, i was talking only about single pole, not a pair of poles.

Comment: You're aware that magnetic monopoles don't exist, right?

Comment: yes, i was saying that the calculated torque was only about 180degrees, that is only under one pole.@Hearth